# WebSharper Operators

Tags: f#, websharper

Being new to WebSharper I am looking for documentation and examples on Operators such as `?` , `?<-` , `-<` , `===.` , `=>` or `|>!`. I did not find it in http://websharper.com/docs. Did I miss it? (there are some listed in http://websharper.com/docs/wig#heading-2-2 but i believe those are only for creating interfaces for existing JS libraries.) Some are listed [here](http://www.websharper.com/question/75876/websharper-operators?tag=f)(3 years ago), do those still apply to UI.Next html?

Answer (score 3):

The operators you mentioned were added by WebSharper for convenience.

For example `?<-` is used to mutate a property of an object.

Here's its implementation:

```
[<Inline "void ($obj[$key] = $value)">]
let ( ?<- ) (obj: obj) (key: string) (value: obj) = X<unit>
```

All the operators can be found in WebSharper code base under [JavaScript.Pervasives.fs](https://github.com/intellifactory/websharper/blob/master/src/stdlib/WebSharper.Main/JavaScript.Pervasives.fs).

Comment: thanks, would this be the same as the inline text `"$obj.$key = $value"` ?

Comment: It would be the same as `void ($obj[$key] = $value)` yes.